# Edit distance with swaps

Tags: edit-distance

Edit distance finds the number of insertion, deletion or substitutions required to one string to another. I want to to also include swaps in this algorithm. For example "apple" and "appel" should give a edit distance of 1.

Answer (score 9):

The edit distance that you are defining is called the *Damerau–Levenshtein distance*. You can find possible implementations on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score -1):

See the algorithm here.

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Dynamic/Edit/

You can give different costs for swap, add, deletions.

```
m[i,j] = min(m[i-1,j-1]
         + if s1[i]=s2[j] then 0 else cost_swap fi,
         m[i-1, j] + cost_insert,
         m[i, j-1] + cost_delete ),  i=1..|s1|, j=1..|s2|
```

Comment: What you have answered is substitution not swaps. In my example given above in the second string swapping "el" gives "le" and thus matches the first string